# Need help with TCHart

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I need to make a simple chart.  Y axis will be a value from 0 to 500, X axis will be a number of seconds (nice if would show minutes, though, as I expect an hours worth of readings). It would be nice if the chart would add scroll bars when the points "fill it up".

Can anyone give me a simple, porgramatic, example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To limit Y-axis value from 0 to 500 use

```
Chart1.LeftAxis.Automatic := False;
Chart1.LeftAxis.Minimum := 0;
Chart1.LeftAxis.Maximum := 500;
```

In X-axis to show date values, use the following code

```
Series1.XValues.DateTime := True;
Chart1.BottomAxis.DateTimeFormat :=  'hh' //or 'nn' or 'ss' as you wish;
```